# Avoid container padding when child is hovered

Tags: html, css

I created a container `div` with some children `div`.
The container has horizontal padding. I need that the children divs change color on hover and I did it, but obviously the container padding did not change color.

To avoid this I can set the padding not to the container but to the children but suppose the container is more complicated, in that case I have to set the padding to all the children and it's not what I want. Is there a smarter solution?

Expected result on hover:

[image]

Here my code so far:

```css
.container {
  background: MidnightBlue;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.row {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.row:hover {
  color: MidnightBlue;
  background: MediumTurquoise;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">item 1</div>
  <div class="row">item 2</div>
  <div class="row">item 3</div>
  <div class="row">item 4</div>
  <div class="row">item 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could solve the issue you are having by setting negative margin and positive padding on `.row` when it's hovered, like below.

> `margin-inline` is a shortcut for `margin-left` and `margin-right`.

```css
.container {
  background: MidnightBlue;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.row {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.row:hover {
  color: MidnightBlue;
  background: MediumTurquoise;
  padding-inline: 20px;
  margin-inline: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">item 1</div>
  <div class="row">item 2</div>
  <div class="row">item 3</div>
  <div class="row">item 4</div>
  <div class="row">item 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can consider a box-shadow

```css
.container {
  background: MidnightBlue;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.row {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.row:hover {
  color: MidnightBlue;
  background: MediumTurquoise;
  box-shadow: 
    -20px 0 0 MediumTurquoise,
     20px 0 0 MediumTurquoise;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">item 1</div>
  <div class="row">item 2</div>
  <div class="row">item 3</div>
  <div class="row">item 4</div>
  <div class="row">item 5</div>
</div>
```