# Getting an element to "Stretch" past padding of the parent container all the way to the edges using CSS only?

Tags: html, css

If we have elements like this:

```html
<main style="padding: 16px; width: 400px; border: 2px dashed gray;">
        <div style="background-color: gray;">header</div>
        <section>content</section>
 </main>
```

Is there a way to get the `div` element to stretch all the way to the edges of the parent past the padding using CSS applied to the div element only?

Someone mentioned using negative margin values for the `div`, and that could work.

I was hoping there's a way to do it without using values directly, in case the CSS padding applied to the parent container changes.

Comment: Give the div a negative margin equal to the parent's padding

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid container padding when child is hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72584387/avoid-container-padding-when-child-is-hovered)

Comment: Negative margins could work.  I was hoping there was a way to tell the child to stretch to the edges without changes values directly, as this would be a more "Flexible solution", since it does not couple itself to the CSS applied to the parent ...

Comment: if you will use position:absolute you will have overlapping issues

Comment: @TemaniAfif could you elaborate please?

Comment: @TemaniAfif  I created a stackblitz with the accepted answer.  It would be really awesome if you could show an overlapping example.  I was planning on using the answer in "Card Design" for the header ... so that I don't have to override the Angular Material default padding ...  https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-zcj5hj?file=index.html,styles.css

Comment: add `font-size: 40px` to the div and you will clearly see the overlap

Comment: Tried it.  I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how much padding is applied to the parent, you can apply negative margin to the child. then (optionally) re-apply padding to the child so your content stay in the original parent's bounds.

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 16px;
  border: 2px dashed gray;
}

.header {
  background-color: gray;
  margin-left: -16px;
  margin-right: -16px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<main class="wrapper" style="width: 400px;">
        <div class="header">header</div>
        <section>content</section>
 </main>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you only want to extend the background, here is an idea using `border-image` but you need to add `overflow:hidden` to the parent as well

```html
<main style="padding: 16px; width: 400px; border: 2px dashed gray;overflow:hidden">
        <div style="border-image:conic-gradient(gray 0 0) fill 0//100vw 100vw 0 100vw;">header</div>
        <section>content</section>
 </main>
```

Comment: Loe this Idea.  Genius!!

Comment: Man I'm so glad you pointed this out.  This ends up being better than what I wanted!! :)

Answer (score 0):

can be solved with `position: absolute`

```html
<main style="padding: 16px; width: 400px; border: 2px dashed gray; position: relative">
        <div style="background-color: gray; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0;">header</div>
        <section>content</section>
 </main>
```